# ERROR OSError: Errno 28 No space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

> AWS Lambda

First I was facing this issue when directly downloading my model from s3 bucket to lambda function `tmp` directory. Therefore to resolve the space error I went for the Docker Container approach. I had to `Dockerized` my model and then uploaded it to `AWS ECR Repository` and then created a lambda function from `container image`, but still I am having this `No Space Left Error`.

Please suggest what could be done.

Comment: Using Amazon EFS is probably one of the solutions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-efs.html.

Comment: It is stated that Container Images got upto 10gb of storage but still this error occurs.

Comment: *Images* can be 10GB.  That says nothing about the disk space on the Lambda itself.  From [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) - "The container image must be able to run on a read-only file system. Your function code can access a writable `/tmp` directory with 512 MB of storage"